# Tsconfig error when installing Quasar testing extension with TypeScript option

Tags: typescript, jestjs, quasar-framework, quasar

When installing the testing extension with TypeScript option I got an error.

I tried @quasar/testing-unit-jest and @quasar/testing
In both results I get an error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: /Volumes/Work/cnd05/services/app/tsconfig.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 305
```

[image]

My tsconfig is:

```
{
"extends": "@quasar/app/tsconfig-preset",
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "types": [
      "quasar"
    ]
  },
}
```

UPD: When I'm trying to install it without TypeScript support all ends up well. Test folder with examples are created and so on. But there is no test folder after I hit that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault. I missed the trailing comma in `tsconfig.json`, which is not allowed by JSON syntax.